# Ring where finitely generated torsion-free modules over it is free

Tags: ring-theory, modules

It is known that if $R$ is a PID, then a finitely generated $R$-module being torsion-free implies that it is free, which results from the Structural Theorem; and the converse also holds if $R$ is a Noetherian domain.

My question is, if $R$ is given as just a domain (without the Noetherian condition), does the converse still hold, i.e. if a finitely generated $R$-module being torsion-free implies that it is free, $R$ is a PID?

I conjecture that this is wrong, where for example taking $R = x\mathbb{Q}[x] + \mathbb{Z}$ which is Bezout could partially fix the problem in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$; but the proof is not clear to me.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes you are right that is the condition I forgot to add. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for updating it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/51922/29335), among integral domains, the condition that "every f.g. torsion-free module is free" is equivalent to being a Bezout domain.

So any non-Noetherian Bezout domain (like the one you suggested) will furnish a counterexample.

Comment: The other answer seems plausible. I am new to module theory and am not quite familiar with commutative algebra. I will accept this answer if I understand the answer you've pointed to me :)

Comment: Sorry I did not quite understand your question - you are looking for a concrete example of what?

Comment: @ARessegetesStery Never mind, i think it was irrelevant to your question.